# Confirming my interpretation on a comment by Vladimir Vapnik

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

In the preface to the first edition of his book *The Nature of Statistical Learning Theory*, Vapnik makes the following comment:

> Between 1960 and 1980 a revolution in statistics occurred: Fisher's paradigm, introduced in the 1920s and 1930s was replaced by a new one. This paradigm reflects a new answer to the fundamental question:
> What must one know a priori about an unknown functional dependency in order to estimate it on the basis of observations?
> In Fisher's paradigm the answer was very restrictive--one must know almost everything. Namely, one must know the desired dependency up to the values of a finite number of parameters. Estimating the values of these parameters was considered to be the problem of dependency estimation.

I understood the following: Suppose you have a function $f: X \to Y$ that you want to estimate by looking at a finite dataset $(x_1, y_1), ..., (x_m, y_m)$, where $y_i \approx f(x_i)$, then Fischer's paradigm had you assume the general expression for $f$, say that $f(x) = w_1\cos(x) + w_2e^{w_3x}$ up to a finite list of parameters ($\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ represents the parameters). In contrast, Vapnik's VC theory required only that you know $f \in \mathcal{H}$, where the VC dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ is finite. Is this interpretation correct?